# Google(gmail login) in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, gmail

pubspec.yaml
google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
error whcih i face
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)

Comment: do flutter clean and then flutter pub get

Comment: i already do that

Answer (score 0):

This is either because you are hot reloading or hot restarting. When you add new libraries which have native implementation in java or swift, it needs a rebuild so that the native code can be loaded.When in case of hot reload and hot restart only dart and flutter code changes are seen.

In a nutshell, rerun the project entirely.

Comment: i rebuild and try again , but it is not working

Comment: Can you please add pubspec file too

Comment: cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1
  table_calendar: ^2.1.0
  bottom_navy_bar: ^5.6.0
  get_it: ^4.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+1
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  autostart: ^0.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6

Comment: Please also add the code that uses this plugin? I don't post in comments. Edit your question.